# How can I configure AD FS Authentication on my project with Net Core 2.1 & Angular

Tags: angular6, adfs, asp.net-core-2.1

As I mentioned on the title, I want to set up AD FS Authentication on my project with Net Core 2.1 in Server & Angular in Client Side, I search a lot of keywords but seems like nothing help me well. So could you show me a tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS runs on Windows Server which does not run .NET Core.

Client side, use adal.js and SPA.

Samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).